# error updating partial in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails view(index.html.erb), i have following structure

```
<div>
   <%= render :partial => "create" %>
</div>

<div>
   <%= render :partial => "show" %>
</div>
```

In controller's create action if i use

```
def create 
  render :update do |page|
     page.replace_html 'show', :partial => 'show'
  end
end
```

I get below error

```
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

because the instance variable doesnt get initialized from controller

If i use

```
def create
    render :file => "_show.erb"
end
```

I get template missing error. because the base layout file is not getting rendered.

I basically want to update the partial on create event.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

The solution :layout => false works.

But, newly added entry doesnt come until page refresh

```
 @entry = Model.find(:all)
```

in the _show.html.erb doesnt get updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this it will surely works..............

```
   def create
     render :partial => "show" ,:layout => false
   end
```

but your page should be name like

```
_show.html.erb
```

Comment: in that case i get undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass, because the instance variable in _show.html.erb doesnt get initialized